# regex make 3 groups: 1st word, last word and rest of sentence

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a sentence

> ("Regex is      really                  confusing")

where the sentence start and end with quotation mark. How do I capture the following ?

> (Regex), (is really) and (confusing)

Currently I have the following regex pattern

```
-r'\"(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)\"'
```

all it does is producing: (Regex), (is   really       confusing) and ().

In case this is something to do with different regex setting, I'm using python's re module calling re.search().group(num)

Comment: `r'^(\S+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)$'`. However, in Python, you may even use string methods to get the final result.

Comment: Problem is what is a word. You might use `^(\w+).+?(\b\w+)$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is do define what a "word" is.

You could for example use

```
^(\w+).+?(\b\w+)$
```

Which would match

```
Regex is really confusing
```

But this won't take into account the dot at the end.

---

Another option would be to use

```
^(\S+).+?(\b\S+)$
```

which would work even with the dot.

---

Altogether you might be looking for [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) instead:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = "Regex is really confusing."
tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)

print(tokens)
# ["Regex", "is", "really", "confusing", "."]
```